# Designing high current test set up

Tags: power-supply, power, current

I need some help designing a high current test. I know just the basic concepts of circuits so any help would be appreciated. I currently have a programmable DC power supply that can supply up to 220 Amps. I need to increment the current up to 200 Amps max through all 5 parts and measure the temperature rise. The current output can be controlled by XFR 12-220 but I need some guidance safely routing the current through each part. I was told to put the circuit in series so that each part can be tested up to 200 amps:

[image: in series]

We rarely test the parts past 10 amps but we need to have the capability of testing up to 220 amps just in case. I was think that if the resistance of one of the parts starts to spike (i.e. R1), the rest of the resistors will not experience the same current.

If the circuit is designed to be in parallel, the maximum current would be limited to 40 amps per part.

[image: parallel]

From reading several posts from this site, I'm guessing that I would have to use some sort of a current limiter that would be adjustable since the current would have to incremented.

What I have: XFR 12-220 Programmable DC Power Supply
What I need: Put incremental current up to 220 amps through 5 parts and measure the temperature rise

Answer (score 0):

Check the datasheet of the resistors and see the maximum power that can be dissipated by them.

So for example the 20 mili Ohms resistor has a power rating 0.25 Watts (which is a typical number for normal cheap resistors that you would find), so if 20 Amps of current flows through it, we have a power dissipation of 8 watts (I^2 * R = 20*20*0.020 = 8 watts) which is above the permissible limits. So check the datasheet of the resistor used or consider 0.25 watts to be the limit. So in this case your resistor wont be able to bear that much current first of all. Therefore check the power rating of the resistor before using it.

And I looked at the XFR 12-220 device data sheet and it already has a current limiter in it as far as I checked. So you can set the maximum current that can be flown in using the device itself so you do not need an additional circuitry for this, this allows you to increment the current using the programmable DC supply itself. Read the datasheet and you would get a better idea.

Comment: Thank you Bhuvanesh. I'm not actually using resistors. The resistors on the diagram actually simulate the parts that I'll be putting current through.

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion, where you put all the test items in series, makes much more sense. Regardless of voltage, when you put items in series, they will ALWAYS have exactly the same current flowing through them. This means that the supply will set the current, and no other current control should be required (you could possibly add a 300A fuse, but it is hard to imagine you would get a failure that caused such a large current).

If you put them in parallel, which I do not recommend, you will not have any control over how they share the 200A. They may share unevenly, or evenly, depending on how they operate (and you have told us nothing about how they operate).

Please note that 200A is a lot of current and will require very large cable, and high quality connections. Otherwise, your wiring may produce more heat than the device under test. To me, this seems like the most challenging part of the whole design. You may need a hydraulic swaging tool to terminate the cables.

Also, would you ever want to test just one item? If so, think about how you will "short out" the unused test locations.

Comment: Hi mkeith, thank you for your response. For the test circuit in series, is my concern valid in that if one of the parts start rising in resistance, the rest of the parts will not experience the same current? The current source is 12v so if the parts collectively gain 12v or more, current will not flow. Also, yes- we would probably test just one item from time to time. That is a scenario that I haven't thought of until now, so thank you.